# Wordpress plugin vs Photoshop CC2015: making animated gifs from folders containing series of .jpgs

Tags: wordpress, action, animated-gif, photoshop-script

I would really appreciate some help/tips as I'm very newbie.
I'm making a Wordpress website with a product catalogue of 1500 products. The client gave me an FTP-acces where he has uploaded 15 images (sequencially numbered) per product.

Question 1:
Does anyone know if there is a possibility in Wordpress to generate animated gifs or via plug-ins?

Question 2:
If no such plug-in exists, I will have to create animated gifs in Photoshop.
I tried to make a combination of script 'load files into stack' and then run an action, but it is still very manual work.
I'm not familiar with scripting, but maybe someone has already done similar work with a script?

Anyway, I appreciate your feedback/effort/tips/help.

Thanks,
Miriam

Comment: Wouldn't be a better option to use a gallery plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I suppose if that were a good option, my WP developer would have told me? I'm the designer, don't know technical things. He told me that I have to deliver all animated gifs...

Comment: Well I don't see any technical reason that don't allow him to use a plugin gallery. Working with gif would be a terrible idea for two reasons : 1) if you need to change a picture, you have to generate again your gif (waste of time) 2) the user can't control a gif, he can't pause on a picture

Comment: OK, but then how do you create a 360° animation, the client isn't going to give me other material, so I only have 15 .jpg images per product. I have 1500 products. Do you have the name of that gallery plug-in? I can ask my developer to check it out.

Comment: Check this out: https://wordpress.org/plugins/360-product-rotation/

Comment: As for question 2, yes you can automate the process via scripting. Essentially load files into stack, animationFramesFromLayers and then save for web as an animated gif

Comment: @Ghoul Fool: thank you, my question is more how can I create a bathc or automated task that takes all the folders and produces animated gifs automatically e.g. combine the scripting from 'load files into stack' with a customized action that creates animated gifs. I have looked at several scripting forums for Photoshop, but as I'm not familiar with scripting, I don't know how to translate their examples into something workable for me.

Comment: Added updated PS script

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in an automated way with `ImageMagick` at the command-line without needing Photoshop. `ImageMagick` is ready installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX (via `homebrew` preferably) and also Windows.

Let's say you were given the following 37 frames by your client, here all arranged into a large montage:

[image]

You can then put them all together into an animated GIF with a 10 centisecond delay between frames at the commandline like this:

```
convert -delay 10 frame* result.gif
```

to get this:

[image]

Comment: @TalwinderSingh: thank you very much, I've asked my developer to check it out and see if we can use this. Especially since the client is already using the mode360.

Answer (score 0):

jpgYup, it's easier with ImageMagick - The script below will work. I've added a second for each frame duration that can be adjusted in the optionals part of the script, right at the top.
The script also has to save out the PSD created, before using save for web to create the animated gif.

ImageMagic is your clear choice here.

```
// ******************************************************
//
// LOAD IMAGES (jpg) AS ANIMATED GIF
// ******************************************************

// *** MUST HAVE ANIMATION WINDOW OPEN
// *** SCRIPT WON'T WORK OTHERWISE!

//OPTIONALS
var frameTime = 1.0;
var tempName = "temp"; // file name for psd

//pref pixels
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var baseDocCreated = false;
var baseImage = "";


var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process");
if (inFolder != null)
{
  var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg)$/i);
}

var exportpath = inFolder;
//alert(inFolder)

// main loop starts here
for(var a = 0 ;a < fileList.length; a++)
{
  // load the frames one by one
  var doc = open(fileList[a]);

  var tempImage = app.activeDocument.name
  // alert(tempImage)

  //create the base document to work with
  if (baseDocCreated == false)
  {
    imageW = app.activeDocument.width.value;
    imageH = app.activeDocument.height.value;
    imageRes = 72;
    imageName = "baseDoc";
    createNewDocument(imageW, imageH, imageRes, imageName)
  }


  var moveTo = app.documents.getByName(baseImage);
  var moveFrom = app.documents.getByName(tempImage);
  moveImage(moveTo, moveFrom)

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

  var rename = tempImage.substring(0, tempImage.length -4);
  app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = rename
  // alert(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name)
}



// now deal with the creation
// of the animated gif
var myPSD = exportpath + "\\" + tempName + ".psd";

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// remove background layer
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;
srcDoc.layers[numOfLayers-1].remove();

// save the psd
psdIt(myPSD);

// get the file path
var filePath = srcDoc.path;

// create animation frames
createAnimationFromLayers();

// set frame timing
setFrameDuration(frameTime);

// save as gif
SaveGifForWeb(filePath);

//close without saving
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);



function createNewDocument(w, h, res, aname)
{
  // alert(w + "\n" + h + "\n" + res + "\n" + aname)
  var docRef = app.documents.add(w, h, res, aname)
  baseImage = "baseDoc"
  baseDocCreated = true;
  srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
}

// FUNCTION psdIt (source doc)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function psdIt (afilePath)
{

  // save out the psd
  var psdFile = new File(afilePath);
  psdSaveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
  psdSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  psdSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;  
  activeDocument.saveAs(psdFile, psdSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}


function moveImage(to, from)
{
  //select the tempImage
  app.activeDocument = from;
  // move from tempImage to the baseImage
  var duplicateLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer.duplicate(to)
}


// function SAVE GIF FOR WEB (path, jpeg quality)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function SaveGifForWeb(saveFile)
{
  var gifOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
  gifOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.COMPUSERVEGIF;  
  gifOptions.interlaced = false;
  gifOptions.colourCount = 256; 
  gifOptions.optimized = true;
  gifOptions.typename = "GIF"; 
  activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, gifOptions);
}

function createAnimationFromLayers()
{
  // =======================================================
  var id9070 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFramesFromLayers" );
  var desc1033 = new ActionDescriptor();
  executeAction( id9070, desc1033, DialogModes.NO );
}


function addFrameTiming(num)
{
  // =======================================================
  var id9576 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc1151 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9577 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref694 = new ActionReference();
  var id9578 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameClass" );
  var id9579 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id9580 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref694.putEnumerated( id9578, id9579, id9580 );
  desc1151.putReference( id9577, ref694 );
  var id9581 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc1152 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id9582 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameDelay" );
  desc1152.putDouble( id9582, num );
  var id9583 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameClass" );
  desc1151.putObject( id9581, id9583, desc1152 );
  executeAction( id9576, desc1151, DialogModes.NO );
}

function selectAllFrames()
{
  // =======================================================
  var id3 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationSelectAll" );
  var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
  executeAction( id3, desc2, DialogModes.NO );
}

function setFrameDuration(num)
{
  selectAllFrames()
  // =======================================================
  var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref1 = new ActionReference();
  var id6 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameClass" );
  var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref1.putEnumerated( id6, id7, id8 );
  desc3.putReference( id5, ref1 );
  var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id10 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameDelay" );
  desc4.putDouble( id10, num ); //num (duration in seconds)
  var id11 = stringIDToTypeID( "animationFrameClass" );
  desc3.putObject( id9, id11, desc4 );
  executeAction( id4, desc3, DialogModes.NO );
}
```